Converting python's regular expression that works only with contains to work in match:
I'm a bit confused about how regular expressions work with python methods. In particular, there's an exercise from leetcode (https://leetcode.com/problems/patients-with-a-condition/description/) that is in which we have to find in the word DIAB1 exists in the string. Seems easy, right? However, I can't seem to get the correct regular expression to fit the str.match() method. I ended using one of the posted solutions which uses str.contains() instead of str.match() but I'd like to get the full regular expression correct.
The three string that causes problems are:
- 'DIAB100 MYOP'
- 'ACNE DIAB100'
- 'SADIAB100'

The regular expression is supposed to match the first two but not the third. I've tried to following ones so far:
r'(?<=\s|^)DIAB1' - ERROR: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern
r'(^|\s)DIAB1' - Fails to match 'ACNE DIAB100'
r'\bDIAB1' - Also fails to match 'ACNE DIAB100'
r'(^| )DIAB1' - Also fails to match 'ACNE DIAB100'

The only solution that worked for me was to use str.contains(r'(^DIAB1)|( DIAB1)'). If I wanted to use str.match() instead, what would be the correct regular expression?

Like re.match, pandas’s .str.match determines

if each string starts with a match of a regular expression.

\bDIAB1 with .str.contains is essentially the correct regular expression solution. You could use match to emulate contains by accepting arbitrary* content at the start of the string with .*\bDIAB1, but there’s just no reason to.
* mind re.DOTALL
